# Log into Windows XP just shows desktop

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

There was a virus on my pc, which I solved using Malwarebytes, but now when I log into my pc it just sits on the wallpaper. It wont load anything up, I cant even do crtl, alt, del.

I left it for a whole evening and it didn't boot anything.

Any ideas, I am looking into "System Restore from Recovery Console"

Comment: Does anything show up at all in safe mode?

Comment: Yep, check safe mode.  You may need to put in a restore disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're going to need to, at the very least, boot into safe mode and see if anything shows up then.  If not, then you're looking at either restoring from a backup, or doing a fresh install.  If you have proper backups, a fresh install may be the best way to go.